# How to add a time stamp on each line of grep output?

Tags: bash

I have a long running process running and I want to monitor its RAM usage. I can do this by watching `top`.  However I would like to be able to log out and have a record written, every minute say, to a shared disk space instead.

My solution which works is:

```
nohup top -b -d 60 -p 10036|grep 10036 >> ramlog.txt &
```

But I would like to know when each line is outputted too. How can I modify the one-liner to add this information on each line?

I know about screen and tmux but I would like to get this simple one-liner working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could add a loop that reads each line from grep and prepends a date. Make sure to use `grep --line-buffered` to ensure each line is printed without delay.

```
nohup top -b -d 60 -p 10036 |
    grep --line-buffered 10036 |
    while read line; do echo "$(date): $line"; done >> ramlog.txt &
```